# Clarification on a theorem?

Tags: complexity-theory, complexity-classes

The proof of theorem 27 in http://www.math.ias.edu/~avi/PUBLICATIONS/MYPAPERS/IKW02/IKW02.pdf suggests
 'If $NEXP = MA$, then $NEXP ⊂ P/poly$".

However looking at it seems it is close to stronger 'If $NEXP = EXP$, then $NEXP ⊂ P/poly$".

1. Can $NEXP\not ⊂ P/poly\implies NEXP\not = EXP$ be plausible?

Comment: The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Comment: We expect references to fulfill the minimal scholarly requirements and be as robust over time as possible. Please take some time to improve your post in this regard. We have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/1201/).